# washing machine set ( Australia ) connectors' position

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, taps

I needed to replace the old with the new one. 
http://www.bunnings.com.au/estilo-chrome-washing-machine-set_p5003030

My problem is that I didn't manage to screw it exactly tight for the connectors to a washing machine to be positioned strictly vertically down. So cold water connector looks rather up, hot down to the side. I must have done something wrong, but it seems too much tension is required to reach vertical down position. I should clarify that I screw the whole tap without disassembling on its parts.

Comment: The way that your question is written, it is not immediately clear what you are asking. I had to come back and read it a 2nd and 3rd time to understand. A photo of your installation would go a long ways toward clarifying the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not my home and I didn't take photos.  My point was - from last acceptable position ( which seems to be loose ) it  was problematic to make  another 360 degrees turn using adjustable spanner ( am I using a right tool ? ).

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common thing that you have to watch assembly of plumbing joints, especially for valve assemblies like this, and stop tightening the joint when the part is in the proper position. If you have gone past the acceptable position sometimes it is possible to back off just a bit to get the right setting. In that case you have to check carefully for leaks. Other times it is necessary to continue tightening the joint to bring the part into proper position. If it appears that this may not be possible because it is just too tight then it may be necessary to disassemble the joint and completely clean the threads out and then apply a bit more TFE thread sealing tape than the first time. Then when re-assembling stop when the joint is in the right position before going too far.

Comment: To summarise your answer, at my judgement -  I either should apply more tension to reach the proper position or by playing with the amount of sealing tape to reach this position earlier. There doesn't seem to be any leak for the current positions, they just look funny.

Comment: I think you got it.